# =SUMPRODUCT alternative for Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, looker-studio

I have used the [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) formula in Google Sheets to work out the total sum made of 7 products in each month of 2022. Screenshot of the data set and formula used in Google Sheets Formula I am using for the total per month:

[image: 2]

However, Data Studio does not seem to accept this formula.

I want to sum the total amount of each product multiplied by the corresponding price for each month it was purchased in. I then want to use this data set in Google Data Studio to show the total amount accumulated for each month.

Google Sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F81cSdnqkoOjEtFWaxjNIdXgeQdwtbzmX2zslT8dXpE/edit?usp=sharing
Google Data Studio Report: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9fcbcd71-0c27-4d40-84d3-aef6ed332354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Sheets needs a header also for column A.
Displaying the data in a Table in Data Studio shows:

[image]

A sum over the column "January" adds the quantity 1 and 4 and the £340. This gives the wrong 345. A quick solve is to apply a filter on the field "Option" and only consider the "SUM" row.
[image]

Another way is to calculate the product by the formula
`January*Price`
Summing over this product is the standard setting.
For each column (here: 12, January to December) such a formula is needed.